# Redirecting to previous page by avoiding required field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 3 pages

1. Login
2. Home
3. Add employee
   Now i've a back button in "Add Employee" page which should redirect to the previous page! but when i click on it the required field validators will turn on!! how can i avoid that for back button?
    I tried using two types of code but both gets stuck in there for validation.

---

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     string prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     Response.Redirect(prevPage);
}
```

And this

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On aspx Page you need to set `CausesValidation = false` for back button. See below

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Back"  />
```

By Adding *CausesValidation = false*. The Validation event will not fire for that button click and your redirect will work properly.

Hope that helps

Comment: Glad that it worked.You can mark the post as answer.